# Is it possible to change icon in moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I am using Moodle 3.2 version. I have applied Boost theme. I need to change some icons for my requirement. For example in header message, notifications icons displayed, need to change that icon.

Is it possible? Please suggest your solution.

Comment: For that you can check moodle docs : https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Using_Label

Comment: For images moodle doc: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_images_in_a_theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the folder containing the installation of your Moodle you will find a folder inside it called “pix”. This folder contains all the core Moodle images and icons.

Search this folder for an icon or image you are looking to replace. Make a record both of the file name (and extension) and the folder it is in. For example, if you were to want to replace the apple icon it is found at

/pix/i/apple.gif

Refer it http://www.ripperdesignandmultimedia.com/2011/08/05/moodle-2-1-changing-the-default-moodle-icons-in-your-custom-theme/

Comment: I deleted the "pix" folder from moodle source . Even though default icons are loaded . I think icons are not loaded from "pix" folder. am i right?

Comment: In moodle there are three main areas in which images are located - core, plugin and theme.